# How to populate values from database using Vuejs

Tags: javascript, laravel, vue.js

I have integrated Vuejs in my laravel project.
Currently My scenario is when i click on my case it navigates me to the detail page but on detail page it does not show me the values which i want to get from the database.

My Vue where I am clicking the case:

```
<div class="col-lg-6">
                        <div class="card">
                            <div class="card-body table-responsive p-0" style="height: 300px;">
                                <table class="table table-hover">
                                    <thead>
                                    <tr>
                                        <th>Case Name</th>
                                    </tr>
                                    </thead>
                                    <tbody>
                                    <tr v-for="kase in cases" :key="kase.id" v-on:click="handleCaseClick">
                                        <td>{{kase.name}}</td>
                                    </tr>
                                    </tbody>
                                </table>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
```

and my script:

```
 methods: {
           
            handleCaseClick() {
              this.$router.push(`/case-log/id`)
            },
}
```

My detail page Vue where it navigated me when i click on case:

```
<template>
    <div class="col-lg-12">
        <div class="card">
            <div class="card-header">
                <h3 class="card-title"></h3>
            </div>
            <div class="card-body table-responsive p-0" style="height: 900px; width: 100%">
                <table class="table table-hover">
                    <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>ID</th>
                        <th>User Id</th>
                        <th>Case Id</th>
                        <th>Message Title</th>
                        <th>Process Type</th>
                        <th>Description</th>
                        <th>Data Load</th>
                        <th>Message Code</th>
                        <th>Log Type</th>
                    </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                    <tr v-for="list in lists">
                        <td>{{list.id}}</td>
                        <td>{{list.user_id}}</td>
                        <td>{{list.case_id}}</td>
                        <td>{{list.message_title}}</td>
                        <td>{{list.process_type}}</td>
                        <td>{{list.description}}</td>
                        <td>{{list.data_load}}</td>
                        <td>{{list.msg_code}}</td>
                        <td>{{list.log_type}}</td>
                    </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>
```

My routes.js

```
        {
    path: '/case-log/:id',
    component: require('./views/detail-page').default
},
```

My web.php
where I am getting the values from database

```
         Route::get('/case-log/{id}', 'CaseLogController@index');
```

My Controller:

```
class CaseLogController extends Controller
{
    public function index($id)
    {
        $case = kase::with('sockets')->find($id);
        return $case->sockets;
    }
}
```

I am unable to show values from database where I am doing wrong? I have also attached my screen shot of my output showing internal server error and also you can see the field but not fetching the values from db.

I really need your help here
thanks in advance.[image]

```
       local.ERROR: Trying to get property 'sockets' of non-object {"userId":1,"exception":"[object] (ErrorException(code: 0): Trying to get property 'sockets' of non-object at C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\admin-lte\\app\\Http\\Controllers\\CaseLogController.php:14)
[stacktrace]
```

My response:

[image]

Consuming api here

```
     <template>
    <div class="col-lg-12">
        <div class="card">
            <div class="card-header">
                <h3 class="card-title"></h3>
            </div>
            <div class="card-body table-responsive p-0" style="height: 900px; width: 100%">
                <table class="table table-hover">
                    <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>ID</th>
                        <th>User Id</th>
                        <th>Case Id</th>
                        <th>Message Title</th>
                        <th>Process Type</th>
                        <th>Description</th>
                        <th>Data Load</th>
                        <th>Message Code</th>
                        <th>Log Type</th>
                    </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                    <tr v-for="list in lists">
                        <td>{{list.id}}</td>
                        <td>{{list.user_id}}</td>
                        <td>{{list.case_id}}</td>
                        <td>{{list.message_title}}</td>
                        <td>{{list.process_type}}</td>
                        <td>{{list.description}}</td>
                        <td>{{list.data_load}}</td>
                        <td>{{list.msg_code}}</td>
                        <td>{{list.log_type}}</td>
                    </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>

<script>

    export default {
        data(){
            return {
                lists: [],
            }
        },
        created() {
            const id = this.$route.params.id;
            axios.get(`/case-log/${id}`).then (response => this.lists = response.data)
        },
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Did you check the error log?

Comment: from where i can see error log?

Comment: In `storage/logs/laravel.log`

Comment: I have added error in my question which is appearing in logs can you please check

Comment: Where I am doing wrong? when i test using postman it showing me the actual result. please look also i have added.

Comment: Use the `findOrFail` method and make sure the `id` is actually being passed

Comment: my url is like this:  http://127.0.0.1:8000/home#/case-log/id  and it should be case-log/1 and now it showing 404 error:http://127.0.0.1:8000/case-log/id 404 (Not Found)

Comment: can you please tell why it occuring i am stuck

Comment: I don't see where you consume the API in vue?

Comment: when i manually change url like this: http://127.0.0.1:8000/home#/case-log/1 it shows me result perfectly

Comment: I have edit where I am consuming my API sorry i forgot to add please check

Comment: hi did you check?